# Query last dataset ahead of time x in a Postgres database efficiently

Tags: postgresql, time-series

How can i efficiently store and retrieve time based datasets that occur in a non periodic manner (sporadically) with Postgres? Here is an example for a definition of such a time based table:

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
  time_ timestamp(0) with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  id integer,
  value integer
)
```

Characteristics of this table are that there is no periodic occurrence of datasets. If you want to generate a protocol of the changes staring with the last value per id for a given point in time (here start_time) for all ids you would have to execute SQL-Statements like this:

-- Retrieve ids and last timestamp for each id ahead of start_time

```
select max(time_),id from example where time_ <= start_time group by id;
```

With these results you can create the query to retrieve the fist datasets for the report.

Now for the problem: When this historic table contains many datasets, then the max(time_)-query will be inefficient, as there is no way for the database to index the table for this query efficiently. Our current solution is to have an additional table for each history table in which we regularly create snapshots for the current status of datasets for the current point in time, so that we only have to lookup the datasets in the table starting at the last snapshot taken ahead of the report start time. Does Postgres have any integral features on board for this task of reporting with last value per id at start time that we can use for this task (e.g. like Informix time series)?

Comment: What indexes do you have on example?  There's no reason that finding the max time for each id should be slow.  Approximately how many rows are in the example table?

Comment: Indexes are on time_ ,id ,but we can add any index that might be useful here. Tables of this kind contain > 100000000 datasets.